# phpmailer работает на windows, на linux нет

Tags: linux, smtp, phpmailer

Один и тот же скрипт с одними и теми же настройками на виндовсе работает, на линуксе нет.

```
<?php 

    include 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->isSMTP();

    $mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.ru';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

    $mail->Username = 'mailfrom@mailru';
    $mail->Password = 'password'; //пароль
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->From = 'mailfrom@mailru'; // из какого эмейла
    $mail->FromName ='куда';
    $mail->addAddress("mailto@mail.ru");
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = "sssssssss";
    $mail->Body = "gggggg";


    $mail->AltBody = 'это альтернативное письмо';

    $mail->SMTPDebug =3;

    if($mail->send()){
    //echo 'письмо отправлено! Для окончания активации, зайдите на свой email и перейдите по ссылке в письме для окончания активации';

    }else{

    echo 'ошибка:' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }

?>
```

phpmailer Version: 5.2.8

php version: 5.6.8

**ошибка, которая происходит на линуксе**

> 2015-07-23 09:26:51 Connection: opening 2015-07-23 09:26:52 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) SMTP connect() failed. ошибка:SMTP connect() failed.

Comment: Видимо, на линуксе нужно открывать 25й порт наружу.

Comment: это нужно в настрйоках самой операционки делать?

Comment: Угу, вот только я не умею пока что управлять файрволлом на линуксе.

Comment: @Юрий, если интернет на этой машине вообще доступен, то, значит, по пути к серверу smtp.mail.ru блокируются соединения на порт 465. чтобы узнать, виновата ли ваша машина, или кто-то дальше по цепочке, посмотрите сами или приложите к вопросу вывод команды, выполненной с полномочиями суперпользователя: `iptables-save`. она покажет всю конфигурацию *netfilter-а* (это подсистема программы *linux*, занимающаяся обработкой сетевых пакетов).

Comment: @Юрий, заодно неплохо бы проверить, доступны ли другие открытые у сервера `smtp.mail.ru` порты: 25, 587 или 2525. это можно сделать, например, программой `telnet`: `telnet сервер порт`. если выведется только одна строчка типа `trying ip-адрес...` и будет «висеть», значит соединения не происходит. прервать ожидание можно с помощью `ctrl+c`. если же программа выведет несколько строк, и среди них `connected to сервер`, то соединение произошло. в этом случае прервать можно так: `ctrl+]`, затем `enter` ввести слово `quit` и ещё раз `enter`.

Answer (score 1):

если интернет на этой машине вообще доступен, то, значит, по пути к серверу `smtp.mail.ru` блокируются соединения на порт 465.

чтобы узнать, виновата ли ваша машина, или кто-то дальше по цепочке, посмотрите сами или приложите к вопросу вывод команды, выполненной с полномочиями суперпользователя:

```
$ iptables-save
```

она покажет всю конфигурацию *netfilter*-а (это подсистема программы *linux*, занимающаяся обработкой сетевых пакетов).

---

заодно неплохо бы проверить, доступны ли другие открытые у сервера `smtp.mail.ru` порты: 25, 587 или 2525.

это можно сделать, например, программой `telnet`:

```
$ telnet сервер порт
```

если выведется только одна строчка типа `trying ip-адрес...` и будет «висеть», значит соединения не происходит. прервать ожидание можно с помощью <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd>.

если же программа выведет несколько строк, и среди них `connected to сервер`, то соединение произошло. в этом случае прервать можно так: <kbd>ctrl+]</kbd>, затем <kbd>enter</kbd> ввести слово `quit` и ещё раз <kbd>enter</kbd>.