# Postfix, JavaMailSender, Spring: Couldn't connect to host, port

Tags: ubuntu, spring, postfix, javamail

**Задача** - при регистрации пользователь получает письмо на оставленный  им email с паролем для входа. Зараннее не известно количество пользователей, которым будет производиться рассылка. Отправка письма должна быть строго с локальной почты.

**Ресурсы** -сервер на ubuntu, серверная часть на spring (в spring используется JavaMailSender), почтовый сервер postfix.

**Проблема** - Со стороны spring не уходят письма.

**Ошибки**:

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port:

В свою очередь, postfix с консоли хорошо отправляет, как локально, так и удаленно. То есть, настроен он правильно, в спам ничего не попадает.

По стороне spring использовано 48 примеров и 25 настроек app.properties, ошибки те же. Складывается впечатление, что я что-то не понимаю в общей архитектуре взаимодействия технологий и компонентов.

**Вопросы** - нужно ли использовать postfix с JavaMailSender вместе для поставленной задачи, или каким образом решается подобная задача, какой стек для решения лучше использовать?

Если у кого есть пример, буду очень признателен.

**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:mail.properties")
public class MailingConfig {

    @Value("${mail.protocol}")
    private String mailProtocol;

    @Value("${mail.smtp.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${mail.smtp.port}")
    private Integer port;

    @Value("${mail.support.username}")
    private String userName;

    @Value("${mail.support.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender javaMailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

        javaMailSender.setProtocol(mailProtocol);
        javaMailSender.setHost(host);
        javaMailSender.setPort(port);
        javaMailSender.setUsername(userName);
        javaMailSender.setPassword(password);

        javaMailSender.setJavaMailProperties(getMailProperties());

        return javaMailSender;
    }

    private Properties getMailProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("customConfig.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.setProperty("customConfig.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.setProperty("customConfig.debug", "false");
        return properties;
    }
}
```

**

```
mail.protocol=smtp
mail.smtp.host=*****
mail.smtp.port=25
mail.support.username=****
mail.support.password=****
```

Comment: вероятно, **как минимум** должно быть `@mail.smtp.host="127.0.0.1"`, `"customConfig.smtp.auth", "false"` и `"customConfig.smtp.starttls.enable", "false"`

Comment: так же, только в профиль  java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; message exceptions (1) are:
Failed message 1: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: 127.0.0.1, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused] with root cause

Comment: поставьте тот порт, который вы настроили в вашем локальном smtp-сервере для приёма обращений по протоколу smtp на адрес 127.0.0.1

Comment: не зная алгоритмов, реализованных в выбранном вами smtp-клиенте, могу предположить ещё, что, вероятно, не следует задавать никаких значений типа username/password. а вообще проверьте, слушает ли ваш smtp-сервер [сконфигурированный вами порт: `telnet 127.0.0.1 порт`](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/522948/178576)

Comment: alexander barakin СПАСИБО! Все заработало, проверил настройки, так как вы советовали!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. стоит убедиться, что ваш smtp-сервер действительно слушает (скорее всего) 25-й порт на локальном ip-адресе `127.0.0.1`. см., например, этот вопрос: [диагностика с помощью telnet](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/541021/178576)
2. если вы не сконфигурировали ваш smtp-сервер на использование аутентификации, то стоит убрать **любые** указания на её использование:

   ```
   properties.setProperty("customConfig.smtp.auth", "true");
   properties.setProperty("customConfig.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

   ...

   mail.support.username=****
   mail.support.password=****
   ```
3. стоит обращаться непосредственно к локальному ip-адресу `127.0.0.1` (не знаю точно, нужны ли в данном случае кавычки):

   ```
   mail.smtp.host="127.0.0.1"
   ```

Comment: Основная причина ошибки, это - не правильное обращение к локальному ip-адресу: mail.smtp.host=vdfe190-35.example.org (пример, не правильно). mail.smtp.host=127.0.0.1 (правильное обращение)

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то, суть проблемы в том, что проект находится **уже** на сервере и требуемое обращение к серверу локальное а не удаленное?

Comment: @alan, **точно** установить причину можете только вы, поэкспериментировав с настройками.

Comment: Спасибо, вы очень помогли)