# диагностика с помощью telnet

Tags: сеть, tcp, faq, telnet

как при помощи программы *telnet* проверить, **доступен** ли указанный tcp-порт на указанной машине, **и слушает** ли этот порт какая-нибудь программа?

---

приветствуются канонические ответы с примерами для разных операционных систем и реализаций программы *telnet*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### unix-подобные операционные системы

вероятно, чаще всего здесь можно встретить bsd- и gnu-реализации: [netkit-telnet](https://packages.debian.org/ru/source/sid/netkit-telnet) и [inetutils-telnet](https://packages.debian.org/ru/source/sid/inetutils). для указанной диагностики разница между ними несущественна.

---

пример неудачного подключения к порту `12345` на каком-нибудь из серверов, в ip-адрес которого резолвится имя `github.com`:

```
$ telnet github.com 12345
Trying 192.30.253.113...
```

прервать неудачную попытку можно с помощью <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd>

---

пример удачного подключения к тому же серверу на порт `22`:

```
$ telnet 192.30.253.113 22
Trying 192.30.253.113...
Connected to 192.30.253.113.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-libssh-0.7.0
```

последняя строчка здесь — это уже информация от программы, слушающей 22 порт на опрашиваемом сервере.

если соединение сразу же не было разорвано слушающей программой (это зависит от её реализации и настроек), то прервать telnet-сессию можно, нажав предложенную программой комбинацию <kbd>ctrl+]</kbd>, а затем клавишу <kbd>enter</kbd>, после чего появится приглашение программы *telnet*:

```
telnet>
```

в котором можно ввести команду `q` (или полностью — `quit`) и нажать клавишу <kbd>enter</kbd>.

### Microsoft Windows

Действия практически идентичны варианту для unix-подобных ОС. В Windows имеется встроенный telnet-клиент, но он может быть отключен. Чтобы его включить нужно выполнить шаги, [описанные на сайте Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6da83bed-c357-4dd7-af1e-26cc2f6c0364).

Когда всё готово, запустить telnet-клиент можно так:

> Пуск - Выполнить - `telnet` - ОК

В открывшемся консольном окне будут видны следующие строки:

```
Welcome to Microsoft Telnet Client
Escape Character is 'CTRL+]'
Microsoft Telnet>
```

Чтобы попытаться открыть тот или иной адрес и порт нужно написать букву `o`, а затем адрес и порт. Например:

```
Microsoft Telnet> o github.com 12345
```

Comment: А где гарантия из первого примера что данный порт не слушается в принципе, несмотря на то, что подключения и не произошло?

Comment: я в вопросе именно так и сформулировал, используя логический оператор «и»: «доступен и слушает». да, возможно стоит расписать это в вопросе подробнее, но я стремился писать лаконичнее и проще. // выделил шрифтом.

Comment: @edem, выделил шрифтом ключевые конструкции. вообще вопросо-ответ написан исключительно с целью ускорения поиска подходящей ссылки при обсуждении каких-нибудь сетевых проблем.

Comment: Вариант для windows, кстати, аналогичный. Только вот прервать попытку соединения по `Ctrl+C` не получается.

Comment: @alexolut, насколько помню, там какое-то ещё окошко открывается собственно с сессией. а вы не могли бы, если у вас есть *ms/windows* под рукой, написать вариант ответа, приложив пару поясняющих картинок?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin окошко с сессией? Всё открывается в текущей консоли, главное, чтобы `telnet-клиент` был установлен в настройках ОС. Все остальные команды эквиваленты тому, что у Вас написано. Поэтому на новый ответ как-то не потянет :)

Comment: @alexolut, мне помнится, что сама программа была не-консольная, и ещё открывалось отдельное окно при удачном подключении. но это было давно (лет 10-15 назад), и, возможно, я что-то путаю, да и версии *ms/windows* были тогда популярны несколько иные, да и реализаций программы *telnet* — явно больше одной. вы говорите об [этой](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6da83bed-c357-4dd7-af1e-26cc2f6c0364)?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin у меня win7, судя по описанию процедуры установки - речь именно о ней.

Comment: @alexolut, я сделал ответ общим. дополните, пожалуйста, хотя бы приведённой вами в комментариях информацией. если окон никаких не открывается, то, вероятно, картинки и не нужны, достаточно форматированного текста.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Причём тут `Ctrl+C`,  если там написано `Escape Character is 'CTRL+]'`
нужно её и жать в телнете (на любой операционке) `CTRL + ]` скобка квадратная