# Не работает брандмауэр (UFW) на Ubuntu 14

Tags: linux, ubuntu

не работает брандмауэр, отображает состояние активных портов, но я не могу закрыть или открыть порт. Запускает ufw с ошибками (мне нужно открыть 700 порт. Я новичок в Linux
спасибо

```
root@client-shosting24:/# ufw enable
ERROR: problem running ufw-init
iptables-restore: line 4 failed
iptables-restore: line 4 failed
iptables-restore: line 80 failed
iptables-restore: line 48 failed
sysctl: permission denied on key 'net.ipv4.tcp_sack'

Problem running '/etc/ufw/before.rules'
Problem running '/lib/ufw/user.rules'

root@client-shosting24:/# ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
700                        ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         DENY        Anywhere
700/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
700/udp                    ALLOW       Anywhere

700                        ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
```

я прописываю так и ничего не происходит

```
  root@client-shosting24:/# sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 700 -j ACCEPT
```

Порт проверял етим сервисом
http://speed-tester.info/check_port.php

sudo iptables-save

```
root@client-shosting24:/# sudo iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Dec  1 16:57:25 2016
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [27655:1329553]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [29810:19196582]
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Dec  1 16:57:25 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Dec  1 16:57:25 2016
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [27655:1329553]
:INPUT ACCEPT [27655:1329553]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [29810:19196582]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [29810:19196582]
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Dec  1 16:57:25 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Dec  1 16:57:25 2016
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [10219:538275]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [10961:6001106]
:ufw-after-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-after-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-output - [0:0]
:ufw-logging-allow - [0:0]
:ufw-logging-deny - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-input - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-output - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-input - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-output - [0:0]
:ufw-track-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-track-input - [0:0]
:ufw-track-output - [0:0]
:ufw-user-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-user-input - [0:0]
:ufw-user-limit - [0:0]
:ufw-user-limit-accept - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-user-output - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-reject-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-track-input
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 700 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 700 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 700 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-reject-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-track-forward
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-reject-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-track-output
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 138 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-logging-forward -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-before-forward -j ufw-user-forward
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-user-input
-A ufw-before-output -j ufw-user-output
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-forward -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-input -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-output -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Dec  1 16:57:25 2016
```

Comment: [openvz?](https://blog.kylemanna.com/linux/ufw-vps/). судя по уровню ваших знаний (красноречивое свидетельсвто которому — желание использовать ufw), вам лучше в эти дебри не лезть. пусть всё будет открыто, как оно и было изначально. просто не забивайте себе голову всеми этими открытиями/закрытиями. // в крайнем случае — обратитесь лучше к хостеру за консультацией по поводу — что можно, а что нельзя использовать внутри вашего контейнера.

Comment: мне нужно открыть порт 700 пишет что открыт , а на самом деле нет.

Comment: изложите, пожалуйста, как вы определили, что «на самом деле нет». прямо в вопросе. нажав [edit].

Comment: а ещё лучше — сразу обратиться к хостеру, чтобы он «пробросил» нужный вам порт с его шлюза внутрь вашей виртуальной машины.

Comment: они сказали что это их не касается))

Comment: ответ [настоящих программистов](http://www.anekdot.ru/id/82175/). вероятно, они намекают на то, что вам выделен внешний ip, и все обращения к нему на любой порт ретранслируются в вашу виртуальную машину. тогда изложите, пожалуйста, прямо в вопросе, как именно вы определили, что «[на самом деле нет](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/598321/?noredirect=1#comment809004_598321)».

Comment: ну, и, вывод `$ sudo iptables-save`, конечно, не помешает.

Comment: Спасибо написал. Порт проверял етим сервисом http://speed-tester.info/check_port.php


анекдот заценил))

Comment: надеюсь весь тот (абсолютно бесполезный мусор), который добавила в цепочки netfilter-а всё-таки зачем то запущенная вами программа ufw, не помешал рассмотреть тот факт, что netfilter, как выше и предполагалось, не блокирует никаких входящих или исходящих пакетов. так что ваш вопрос можно считать исчерпаным. // разбирайтесь с запущенным вами процессом, который якобы должен слушать некий порт на внешнем ip, и с тем, как пользоваться хотя бы telnet-ом для диагностики. удачи!

Comment: как мне посмотреть что порт открыт?
Спасибо за ответ

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/541021/178576

Comment: спасибо за ответ но порт закрыт(                                              

`Microsoft Telnet> o 153.92.208.181 700
Подключение к 153.92.208.181...Не удалось открыть подключение к этому узлу, на порт 700: Сбой подключения
Microsoft Telnet>`

Comment: либо его не слушает никакой процесс.

Comment: ето мой скайп zimkoanvt можете помочь(?