# Nginx + fastCGI -как установить на два хоста?

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm, fastcgi

Здравствуйте.

Есть два хоста. На первый установил nginx, запрашиваю index.html - возвращает, все работает.

На второй хост установил php(командой sudo apt-get install php-fpm php-mysql).

Код nginx:

```
server {
listen 443;
ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/xxxx.com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/xxxx.com.key; 

root /var/www/xxxx.com/html;

index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name xxxx.com www.xxxx.com;

location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ \.php$ { 
include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
fastcgi_pass xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:9000; #ip второго хоста на котором установлен php
#include fastcgi_params;
#fastcgi_index index.php; 
#fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; 
#fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
} 
}

server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
server_name xxxx.com www.xxxx.com;
return 301 https://xxxx.com;
}
```

В файле /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf на втором хосте заменяю строку listen = /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock на listen = XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:9000 (где иксы это Ip этого же хоста). Пробовал так же писать listen = 127.0.0.1:9000.

В папку с сайтом на первом хосте добавляю файл Index.php в нем вывод строки Hello World. Однако страница не открывается а выдает 504 ошибку спустя секунд 30 примерно.

Пингуются оба хоста с друг друга нормально. В чем может быть дело? Спасибо.

Comment: проверьте, что tcp-соединение устанавливается: `$ telnet XXX.XXX.XXX.XX 9000`. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/541021/178576

Comment: Если выполнить эту команду на хосте на котором установлен php то выводит
Trying XXX.XXX.XXX.XX
Connected XXX.XXX.XXX.XX
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.

Если же выполняю эту команду с хоста на котором nginx(но айпишник тот же, то есть хоста на котором пхп) то пишет:
Trying XXX.XXX.XXX.XX...

и все.

Comment: вот и разбирайтесь именно с этим, а не с (цитирую метки) nginx, php, php-fpm, fastcgi. которые никаким образом не имеют отношения к отсутствию связи.

Comment: А можете более детально подсказать? 
9000 порт прослушивается, в лог никаких ошибок не пишется, ни в одном мануале по настройке nginx на одном хосте а php-fpm на другом не встретил ничего похожего, везде одно и то же - на стороне nginx указать fastcgi_pass XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:9000, на стороне php - прослушивать этот порт, всё.

Comment: ещё раз: отсутствие связи между двумя вашими компьютерами не имеет никакого отношения ни к nginx, ни к php-fpm.

Comment: Спасибо большое за подсказку, что не там ищу.