# Ошибка 502 Gateway, error connection refused

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

Я просто еще один горе админ, пытающийся перейти на vps. Перерыл первую страницу гугла, говорят про неправильный порт, но это я проверил

Имеется Ubuntu 16.04, Nginx, PHP7, MySql и все такое, сам сайт на WordPress. Все установил, все вроде должно работь но нет - 502 Gateway. В логе имеем

```
2017/06/17 17:43:14 [error] 14128#14128: *58 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: [ip], server: ***.ru, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "***.ru"
```

/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf :

```
...
user = www-data
group = www-data
...
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
...
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
```

В настройках сервера:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  ***.ru;
        root   /var/www/html/***.ru;
        index  index.php index.html;

        location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files       $uri $uri/      =404;
        }
        location ~* ^.+.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                access_log        off;
                expires           max;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                # fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;

                fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT    /***.ru;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /***.ru$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED  /***.ru$fastcgi_script_name;

                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING     $query_string;
                fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD   $request_method;
                fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE     $content_type;
                fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH   $content_length;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
                fastcgi_ignore_client_abort     off;
                fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
                fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
                fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
                fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
                fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
                fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }
        ## Disable viewing .htaccess & .htpassword
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny  all;
        }
}
```

$ ps aux | grep fpm:

```
root     14596  0.0  6.7 186260 34284 ?        Ss   18:20   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
www-data 14599  0.0  1.2 186260  6140 ?        S    18:20   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data 14600  0.0  1.2 186260  6140 ?        S    18:20   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
admin    14799  0.0  0.1   4688   880 pts/0    S+   18:37   0:00 grep --color=auto fpm
```

telnet:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

log php-fpm полнстью из подобных записей:

```
[17-Jun-2017 17:05:05] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 10219
[17-Jun-2017 17:05:05] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[17-Jun-2017 17:05:05] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
[17-Jun-2017 17:05:16] NOTICE: Terminating ...
[17-Jun-2017 17:05:16] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
[17-Jun-2017 17:05:16] NOTICE: configuration file /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf test is successful
```

Comment: процесс интерпретатора-то работает (`$ ps aux | grep fpm`)? соединения [принимает (`$ telnet 127.0.0.1 9000`)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/541021/178576)?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin спасибо, что не остались равнодушным)
`root     14596  0.0  6.7 186260 34284 ?        Ss   18:20   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
www-data 14599  0.0  1.2 186260  6140 ?        S    18:20   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data 14600  0.0  1.2 186260  6140 ?        S    18:20   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
admin    14623  0.0  0.1   4688   884 pts/0    S+   18:24   0:00 grep --color=auto fpm
`

Comment: Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
^CConnection closed by foreign host.
Видимо, все работает

Comment: значит, смотрите в [логи интерпретатора](http://php.net/manual/ru/install.fpm.configuration.php#error-log). // вы, вроде, не новичок, а структурированную информацию пытаетесь выложить в комментарии вместо самого вопроса.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin весь файл состоит из таких блоков:

`[17-Jun-2017 18:17:32] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 14551
[17-Jun-2017 18:17:32] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[17-Jun-2017 18:17:32] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
[17-Jun-2017 18:20:23] NOTICE: Terminating ...
[17-Jun-2017 18:20:23] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
[17-Jun-2017 18:20:23] NOTICE: configuration file /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf test is successful
`
Я извиняюсь, ейчас все продублирую(в голове щелкнуло, что как-то некрасиво получается, но не догадался)

Comment: [первая ссылка](https://github.com/magenx/Magento-Automated-Server-Configuration-from-MagenX/issues/73) при поиске строки `systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60656/discussion-between--malginovdesign--and-alexander-barakin).